# Is this function composed of non-invertible functions invertible?

Tags: functions, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

Consider a nonlinear function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Next define $g:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ as per:
\begin{align}
(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4) = g(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = (f(x_1,x_2,x_3), f(x_2, x_3, x_4)).
\end{align}
Can $g$ be invertible even though $f$ is not? I don't see why not, even though it at the same time sounds counter-intuitive to me. Edit: $f$ shouldn't "drop" any of the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ drop the middle element. That is : $f(x, y, z) = (x, z)$. Then, $g(x, y, z, w) = (f(x, y, z) , f(y, z, w)) = (x, z, y, w)$, which is invertible.

Comment: What if no elements are "allowed" to be dropped (not sure how to better phrase such restriction)?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain that f should be a nonlinear function of all the elements

Comment: Then replace $f$ with an non-linear injective function, say $f(x,y,z) = (x^3, z^3)$

Comment: but that doesnt adhere to my added restriction that none of the elements being "dropped", apologies I dont know how to better phrase that.